how to actually implement a serverless function on Vercel for Vite code for production environment?
My code works perfectly fine using Vercel Dev, and a Postman request to the API route, but still, it says "Error: Error: Failed to fetch response."
I think the error may be a wrong fetch location, where somehow,the post request changes moving from local to production because the post request says "https://vercel.app/server/api/virtualassistant" instead of the correct path which is "https://vercel.app/api/virtualassistant"
my local environment uses the correct post request /api/virtualAssistant
image of error
my fetch code:
try {
      const myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      myHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');

      const response = await fetch('/api/virtualAssistant', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: userMessage }),
        redirect: "follow"
      });

      console.log(response.status)
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch response. Request failed with status ${response.status}');
      }
  
      const responseData = await response.json();
      const generatedText = responseData.text; // Access the text from the response object
      
      console.log(generatedText);

    } catch (error) {

      console.error("Error:", error);

Accessing the API route on my browser works
My Postman Request code, that works, is

const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

const raw = JSON.stringify({
  "message": "what is an apple"
});

const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: "follow"
};

fetch("placeholder", requestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));

I switched to 'isomorphic-fetch',
tried doing the following code to fetch full URL
  const isLocal = import.meta.env.VITE_VERCEL_URL === "local";
  const vercelUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_VERCEL_URL
  const domain = isLocal ? 'localhost:3000' : vercelUrl;
  const protocol = isLocal ? 'http://' : 'https://';

  const createUrl = (route) => {
    const baseUrl = `${protocol}${domain}`;
    return `${baseUrl}${route}`;
  };

  const url = createUrl('/api/virtualAssistant');

I tried and have set the server side cors on the serverless function
const virtualAssistant = async (req, res) => {

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

My vercel.json file looks like this
{
    "rewrites": [
      { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }
    ]
  }

Still the error remains exclusively on production
How do I fix this?
